# Can anyone help me complete this quine in Ruby? - I'm so very close

Tags: ruby, quine

```
s="s=@;print(s.sub('@', s))";print(s.sub('@', "\"#{s}\""))
```

This code is supposed to print out an exact copy of itself but instead I am getting the following:

> s="s=@;print(s.sub('@', s))";print(s.sub('@', s))%

It's almost there but the problem I'm having is getting the `s` variable in the `s.sub` parameter matching in the output string.

See this for more information on quine's: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29

Thanks for any help

Comment: not sure I understand can you please specify your desired result.

Comment: apologies for not being clearer, the result should be the output of the code itself.  "A quine is a non-empty computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output".  I've almost got it doing this - just as a programming exercise but can't quite complete it!

Comment: When you say output you mean the "printed string"? Because the actual return value for print is `nil` but the "printed string" is currently `s="s=@;print(s.sub('@', s))";print(s.sub('@', s))` so if you just add something like I want it to return this and an example I and many others would be glad to assist.

Comment: Yes, I meant the printed string, not the actual output.  I've updated the question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: Okay so the variable `s` equals the String `"s=@;print(s.sub('@', s))"` but then you want to subsitute the `@` symbol with `s` again? so it would be `"s=\"s=@;print(s.sub('@', s))\";print(s.sub('@', s))"` because it substituted the original `@` for `s`. Which is what you asked it to do. What is your expectation because your "application" cannot actually be processed (using something like eval as your link does) because `s=@` is not valid ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s="s=@;print(s.sub('@', 34.chr + s + 34.chr))";print(s.sub('@', 34.chr + s + 34.chr))
```